# 2 urls in one ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was wondering if I can do this jquery ajax on my code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "functions/ajaxNca_add.php", "functions/ajaxNca_update.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(response){
    // show success
    alert(response.a);
}
```

The code above is just an example and I knew that it's not working. How can I call 2 php script in just one ajax request in jquery ? Can someone help ?

Comment: Why just one request?

Comment: Your `success` function expects responce from one php-script. How did you manage to handle two responce from two php-scripts?

Comment: you can not use more than on url in ajax. but you can implement the functionality of two php files in one and return the result in success.

Answer (score 5):

No you can not do this. If you will look at [jquery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you will see that url accepts only string, not an array of stings.

You should either make two requests, or create another `*.php` entry point which will combine both php scripts and make a call to this one.

Answer (score 5):

You can't call 2 url simultaneously.but you can call one after another.

```
        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "functions/ajaxNca_add.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(response){
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "functions/ajaxNca_update.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(response){
//responce
}

    });
}

    });
```

or

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          url: "functions/ajaxNca_add.php", 
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
 async: true,
          success: function(response){
//responce
}});
 $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          url: "functions/ajaxNca_update.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
 async: true,
          success: function(response){
//responce
}});
```

async: true - synchronizes your ajax calls

Comment: You can't put two URLs in an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

More simple way :

You can also do one ajax call to `functions/ajaxNca_add.php` file, and include second file 
`functions/ajaxNca_update.php` in first ajax file.

So from one ajax call, you can access 2 files at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the object first then you need to call ajax two times by changing the url.

```
var ajaxObj = {
    type: "POST",
    data: thisForm.serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
        if(response.status=="success"){
            dataLayer.push({'event' : 'requestdemo_form_submitted', 'request_demo_submit_event_gtm' : 'request_demo_submit_event_gtm'});
            $('.sidebar-req-sec').addClass('hide');
            $('.sidebar-req-sec-thnk').removeClass('hide');
            $('.sidebar-req-sec-thnk').addClass('show');
        }
    }
};
//url1 ajax 
ajaxObj.url = 'url1';
jQuery.ajax(ajaxObj);
//url2 ajax
ajaxObj.url = 'url2';
jQuery.ajax(ajaxObj);
```